# how to add remove class using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried with this code but it not working for me

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0];
    if(total < 15){
      element.classList.add("otherclass");
    }else{
      element.classList.remove("otherclass");
    }
```

throwing error for me

```
<div ClassName="dropdown">
</div>
```

Comment: The error is quite clear ...

Comment: Please add the HTML where you have element(s) with the classname "dropdown".

Comment: Having read the error message, what do you suppose the value of `element` is? Why do you think that might be?

Comment: Are you executing this JS code after the DOM has been loaded?

Comment: i am using in react js

Comment: Your HTML should have 'class' not 'ClassName', assuming is pure HTML.

Comment: @Ciprianis `className` is the correct property. `class` is not. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

Answer (score 1):

To refer to the `class` attribute of an element via JavaScript, you need to use the [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property.

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0];
if(total < 15){
  element.className+=" otherclass"; // Space before the string when there are other classes present.
}else{
  element.className.replace("otherclass", "");
}
```

You could break your [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) string down, delimited by spaces, in to an array and then have more control over your classes, of course you'd have to implode them back in to a string before implementing it.

Although [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) (among other DOM Management libraries) already offers this.

**EDIT**

Please see this JSFiddle for a working example...

https://jsfiddle.net/fq8jwLyx/

Comment: thank u for the reply i am getting an error `className` i am using react js

Comment: The JavaScript you posted in your question has nothing to do with ReactJS. Please post your entire error message.

Comment: i am using this code in react js `TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined`

Comment: It's the first line of code that has the problem causing the error. `getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0]` returned undefined. This is likely caused by the invalid HTML.

Comment: @csmckelvey is more than likely correct. The code otherwise works, kindly refer to the JSFiddle in my edit. You need to ensure that your elements are instantiated inside the DOM.